# global.R don't start

Tags: r, shiny

I'm wondering why global.R doesn't start when i launch my app from Rstudio.
It seems, of what i understood, that global.R must be run once as i launch my app, but instead Rstudio give me an error that it could not find the function that i have defined in the global.R file.
After running global.R by hand with ctl+alt+r then i can launch my app and it recognize the function and works well all during the time i use the R session. I'm not publishing on the web but works just in local.
Do i missed something?
Thanks.

Comment: is `global.R` located in the same folder as `server.R` and `ui.R`?

Comment: Yes it is. But i'm using an app.R instead of server.R and ui.R

Comment: You could possibly `source("global.R")` to resolve this as one of your first lines in `app.R`

Comment: Yes that's what i have done and it works but i would like to know why it doesn't start alone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(R version 3.5.2 and shiny 1.2)

The content of `global.R` is usable only if the shiny app is made of `server.R` and `ui.R`. The content of `global.R` **is ignored** if the app is made of a unique `app.R` file.

Splitting your `app.R` in `server.R` and `ui.R` will 
resolve your issue.

Comment: This is very confusing with the get started of shiny where they say:

Note: Prior to version 0.10.2, Shiny did not support single-file apps and the ui object and server function needed to be contained in separate scripts called ui.R and server.R, respectively. This functionality is still supported in Shiny ...

In fact it is say that we must go with app better than with server and ui because these former are still supported!!! but for how many time?

But global.R is not launch automatically with app. 
You're right ! thx

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP asked about why `global.R` is not read when the architecture relies only a single `app.R`, it is because of how the app is started.

If it is started via:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Then the application is considering these two functions without running anything beforehand, i.e. neglecting `global.R` contents. There is, however, the `onStart` parameter that can be supplied to `shinyApp` to run something before the app starts, and its description resolves a great deal of confusion:

> onStart:  A function that will be called before the app is actually run. This is only needed for shinyAppObj, since in the shinyAppDir case, a global.R file can be used for this purpose.

It looks to me that when the application is split into `server.R` and `ui.R`, `global.R` is automatically included by means of running the app through `shinyAppDir`.

The solutions I found in case one wants to strictly use a single `app.R` code file and perform some routines prior to starting the app are:

- Tinker with `onStart` parameter inside `shinyApp` call
- Source `global.R` as @tic-toc-choc [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948774/3429115)